# Matplotlib draw outside plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to draw rectangles under a plot. I tried using matplotlib.patches Rectangles but the rectangles only show up if I don't plot something into the subplot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

t1 = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.9)
t2 = np.arange(0.0, 50.0, 0.02)

plt.figure(1, figsize=(14, 6))
plt.subplot(211)

# If I uncommend this line, the rectangles will disappear
# plt.plot(t1, t1, 'bo', t2, t2, 'k')

# Draw some rectangles under the plot
someX, someY = 0.1, -0.3
currentAxis = plt.gca()
tri = Rectangle((someX - .1, someY - .1), 0.005, 0.2, fill='b', alpha=1)
currentAxis.add_patch(tri)
tri.set_clip_on(False)

someX, someY = 0.5, -0.3
currentAxis = plt.gca()
tri = Rectangle((someX - .1, someY - .1), 0.005, 0.2, fill='b', alpha=1)
currentAxis.add_patch(tri)
tri.set_clip_on(False)

plt.show()
```

All I want is to draw some lines under the plot at a certain position (like in a rugplot).

Thanks

Comment: the patches don't disappear.  When you don't use `plot` the axis limits are `(0,1)` (standard values). However, when you use `plot` the limits get adjusted automatically (to something in the range of `t1` and `t2`) and thus the rectangles get very small.

Comment: I have a follow up question with two scales:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31334716/matplotlib-draw-outside-plot-two-scales