# Matplotlib draw outside plot (two scales)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31318098/matplotlib-draw-outside-plot) question I tried to draw a rectangles outside a plot. After your help I got this running but now I have problems if I use a two scale axis:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
t = np.arange(0.01, 10.0, 0.01)
s1 = np.exp(t)
ax1.plot(t, 'b-')
ax1.set_xlabel('Query sequence')
ax1.set_ylabel('siRNA counts', color='b')
# Make the y-axis label and tick labels match the line color.
ax1.set_ylim([0, 25])
for tl in ax1.get_yticklabels():
    tl.set_color('b')


ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot([1,20,30,40], [0.09,0.5,0.1,0.3], 'r.')
ax2.set_ylabel('Pair probabilities', color='r')
ax2.set_ylim([0.0, 1.0])
for tl in ax2.get_yticklabels():
    tl.set_color('r')

someX, someY = 5.5, -5.3
currentAxis = fig.gca()
tri = Rectangle((someX - 5.1, someY - 5.1), 5.005, 5.2, fill='b', alpha=1)
currentAxis.add_patch(tri)
tri.set_clip_on(False)

plt.show()
```

The rectangle wont show up again. Any help is very appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Well the y coordinate of your rectangle is `-5.3-5.1=-10.4` and has a height of `5.2`, so it will go up to `-5.2`. And since you last used `ax2`, `plt.gca()` will return `ax2`, for which you set the limits to `(0,1)`. So again the rectangle is there, but not in the view of the plot.

Comment: Ok, now I got it...Sorry, it was somewhat confusing to me...